# Simple SKScene randomly drops to 40fps

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, core-animation

I have a simple SKScene generated in code that gets presented from a SKView in a storyboard. This scene contains a single 30x18 pixel art image, no animations, no updates.

For some reason, such a simple scene is randomly falling to 40FPS with no clear explanation. CPU usage is always ~14% or lower in the app, so this seems extremely unnecessary.

I couldn't find many helpful posts on this issue, besides one that claimed CADisplayLink caused this issue. I don't use this framework, however my app utilises CAGradientLayer, leading me to believe Core Animation in general causes this issue.

Disabling it in my app significantly reduced the frequency of this issue. Where I would have seen it 20 times before, I now see it once. However, it's still happening. Does anyone have any suggestions on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This happens for me too, but only on 1 device (an iPad 6th gen), other devices like iPhones never experienced this. On the iPad, it works fine most of the time, but from time to time the frames drop to around 32-36 and stay like that, even though there's not much going on in the scene. It seems like it is in some sort of power saving mode. And as randomly as it starts, after a while it comes back to 60 fps. No idea why is this happening, nor I can replicate it.

Comment: @Calin Do you possibly have any instances of Core Animation or UIView.animate running in your app? Deactivating them resolved this issue for me.

Comment: I do not have any specific Core Animation or UIView.animate code, I simply use the [SpriteKit's Frame-Cycle Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/responding_to_frame-cycle_events) which I believe are based on CADisplayLink. So I don't really have anything to deactivate, but your discovery is interesting. In my case, the issue only seems to happen on that particular iPad, and once it starts lagging, if I continue to play the game, after a few mins it starts behaving normally again, without anything changing. Really weird.

Comment: @Calin While researching this issue before I found my solution, I read using the update(_:) method may introduce this issue too. Perhaps that could be causing the issue here? In addition, is it a specific iPad model or just that one physical iPad? It may be a device-based issue.

Comment: That is a good question, but I cannot know if it's only that physical iPad because I don't have access to another iPad of the same model. So far I've only seen this issue on that one iPad. I also disabled everything in the `update(_:)` method, and the issue was still there. So this confirms there's not a performance problem. And it randomly goes away. The metrics while this is happening all look good, on the low end, but the FPS stays consistent at 32-36. It could be a problem only on this physical device, although I can't understand why, everything else works fine on the device.

Comment: Have you tried it in a simulator of the same model? This is quite the weird bug. I'd also recommend you open a new question about it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears my hunch was correct; Core Animation (and perhaps UIKit Animation) interferes with SpriteKit. Disabling any active instances of `CABasicAnimation` and `UIView.animate` in my app when the scene is loaded resolved the issue.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have optimized your SKView settings. In particular, check the following properties:
ignoresSiblingOrder: Set this property to true to avoid enforcing z-order rendering. This can improve performance when you have a simple scene.
Check it:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520215-ignoressiblingorder

shouldRasterize: If you're using CAGradientLayer or other Core Animation layers, try setting the shouldRasterize property of the layer to true. This will cache the layer contents as a bitmap, potentially improving performance at the cost of memory usage.
Check it:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410905-shouldrasterize

Reduce SKScene updates: If you don't need any updates or animations in your SKScene, you can remove the update method to save CPU cycles.
Optimize assets: Even though you're using a small pixel art image, make sure that it's optimized. Use compressed textures whenever possible, and ensure the image is in a power-of-two size  32x32 instead of 30x18.
Test on different devices: Test your app on various devices to see if the issue persists across all of them. This will help you determine whether it's a device-specific issue or a more general performance problem.

Comment: These are some great suggestions for general optimisation that will probably help someone else having this issue, but in my case this unfortunately didn't work.